# Custom live ubuntu and drivers

Tags: drivers, live-usb, custom-distributions, custom-installer

I want to create a custom live Ubuntu yet one thing concerns me: drivers.

There are softwares such as Respin which takes the currently installed and customized linux distro and converts it to an iso file. I need to know how does this specific software or the other similar softwares handles the drivers. Do they keep the driver configurations of the system that I am creating iso from OR do they remove them so that each time I boot, the drivers are installed from scratch as if I am running default Ubuntu live?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how does this specific software or the other similar softwares handles the drivers

- All generic drivers are present on the ISO and are installed (ie. copied) to the system.
- During a boot the system recreates the /dev/ section (see `/sbin/MAKEDEV` and `/dev/MAKEDEV.local`) ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/MAKEDEV.8.html)).

Comment: Asking this just to be sure: the live version, by definition, doesn't come with /dev/.Thus everytime I boot a live distro, no matter which software I use to create one, creates the driver specific files from scratch as long as its sane?

Comment: Yes, drivers on the live session are generated and loaded into memory as they are needed.