# Custom network driver for ubuntu installer

Tags: networking, drivers, system-installation, compiling

For getting my Realtek Chip RT8111G to work I have to download the driver from the Realtek page and run their compilation/installation script. (With the default kernel driver it does not work, with the r8169-dkms package neither.)

How can I integrate the realtek driver setup script into the Ubuntu installer so network configuration via dhcp will succeed during the setup? How is it possible to compile (needs package build-essential) and load a kernel module before setup starts or to integrate a pre compiled kernel module into the installer?

update: recent Ubuntu versions provide a newer version of the r8169-dkms package (http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/) Is it possible to install this package into the running ubuntu installer before network configuration takes place?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/835592/custom-live-ubuntu-and-drivers